# Adding Table of Contents to existing PDF

Tags: pdf, table-of-contents, include

How can I add a Table of Contents (TOC) to an existing PDF?

I have an existing PDF (scanned notes from a class). I'd like to improve this basic scan as much as possible. I do not think that any OCR is good enough to recognize handwriting, so I cannot make it searchable. But I would like to manually modify it by adding a TOC in the beginning that links to parts of the document.

One way could be to split the PDF into separate documents, then have:

```
\section{Part One}
\include{part1.pdf}
\section{Part Two}
\include{part2.pdf}
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to do this without splitting it up.

Comment: @gull there is already an accepted answer so I think the posters problem was solved in 2011.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use package `pdfpages` and then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The first section name}% or chapter
\includepdf[pages={1-10},linktodoc,linktodocfit=/Fit]{texte/dtk/dtk11-1/komoedie.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The second section name}% or chapter
\includepdf[pages={11-19},linktodoc,linktodocfit=/Fit]{texte/dtk/dtk11-1/komoedie.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The third section name}% or chapter
\includepdf[pages={20-29},linktodoc,linktodocfit=/Fit]{texte/dtk/dtk11-1/komoedie.pdf}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The forth section name}% or chapter
\includepdf[pages={21-39},linktodoc,linktodocfit=/Fit]{texte/dtk/dtk11-1/komoedie.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting/disappointing that pdfpages' linktotoc option is harder than just doing this manually, since the rest of the package is excellent.

Comment: @Will do you mean `addtotoc`?

Comment: @Herbert Thank. It sort-of works. It appears correct, but the TOC links (and sidebar links) all go to the bottom of the local TeX text document. (page 2, after the TOC and title page). The TOC link says "page 17", but just jumps to the bottom of the local doc (the top of all the included pages).

Comment: @mankoff: I edited the answer. There is now a working example.

Comment: @mankoff — yes, sorry. My brain confused `linktodoc` and `addtotoc`.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}` is also useful, otherwise links do not point directly at the beginning of the page.

Comment: Hey, when trying chapter, I got error.

Comment: create a complete example. I have no idea what you really did.

Comment: I have no problem with `\documentclass{book}` and changing `section` to `chapter`

Comment: General note: if you try this for a book, and want to add `chapter`s and `part`s instead of `section`s, don't forget to change the document class to `\documentclass{book}`. Otherwise you'll get error messages like `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`. [This comment is a replacement for my earlier comments.]

Comment: In order to add subsections, you just have to change the `\addcontentsline`, and the `\phantomsection` from hyperref will do the job (in case someone tried to use a "\phantomsubsection" command...)

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Can you elaborate on how to add subsections?

Comment: @AlJebr yes, I meant that instead of:
`\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...}`, you have to change like this:
`\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{...}`